# Build a Docker image of an app using Gradle

Tags: docker, gradle, jhipster

I have made an application using JHipster, of which I want to create a Docker image using Gradle. I was following [this guide](https://www.jhipster.tech/docker-compose/#3) but when I run the command `./gradlew bootWar -Pprod buildDocker`, it gives an error:

> Task 'bootWar' not found in root project 'seodin'. Some candidates
>   are: 'bootRun'.

I also tried running the command with 'bootRun', but I get the following error in this case:

> Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
>   Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I am stuck at this point and any help is appreciated. [Note: Java and all other dependencies are installed and the JHipster app is working fine on localhost]

Comment: there's no "Jhipster App"! JHipster is a generator for web application based on Spring Framework and Angular! please post some your pom.xml and make sure that you've included [WAR plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) in your project.

Comment: Hi @RoxcH, thanks for the correction. I checked in build.gradle and it includes "apply plugin: 'war' ". Also, I am not using pom file, but you may see my build.gradle file here: https://pastebin.com/mE5JSjeS. Thanks!

Comment: From reading your build.gradle file, I see that you are not on JHipster latest version, for you the command should be: ./gradlew bootRepackage -Pprod buildDocker. You should have a link to the correct versioned documentation in the README file generated by jhipster.

Comment: @PierreBesson I get this error with the bootRepackage command: org.newsclub.net.unix.AFUNIXSocketException: Permission denied (socket: /run/docker.sock). Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: Yes it seems like you need to be root to access your docker daemon (try sudo or adding your user to the docker group, please refer to the Docker docs).